# Forwarding the min and max values of BackgroundWorker to use the function correctly

Tags: vb.net, backgroundworker

I have been struggling for several days to find a solution on how to properly incorporate BackgroundWorker into my Feature and with that I have the ability to properly display the process development, process stop, report.

this is my code

```
 Private Sub Frm_ImportLeumobileGK_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
        Me.BackgroundWorker1.CancelAsync()
        Me.Timer1.Enabled = False
        Me.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel
        e.Cancel = True
    End Sub

     Private Sub Btn_OK_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_OK.Click
        ListView1.Items.Clear()
        resetCounter()
        BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
    End Sub


      Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
        Dim worker As BackgroundWorker = TryCast(sender, BackgroundWorker)
        TestPut_All_CDRs_To_FakturaPos(worker, e,
                         MasterMandantConnectionString:=MasterMandantConnectionString,
                         StartDate:=dtp_Start.Value,
                         EndDate:=dtp_End.Value,
                         min_Nr:=tb_Min_Nr.Value,
                         max_Nr:=tb_Max_Nr.Value)
    End Sub

      Sub TestPut_All_CDRs_To_FakturaPos(worker As BackgroundWorker, e As DoWorkEventArgs, MasterMandantConnectionString As String, StartDate As Date, EndDate As Date, min_Nr As Integer, max_Nr As Integer)
        Dim n As Integer = 0
        Dim MobCdrs As List(Of String)
        ProgressBar1.Maximum = (max_Nr - min_Nr)

        For Mob_Nr = min_Nr To max_Nr
            n += 1
            If worker.CancellationPending Then
                e.Cancel = True
            Else
                MobCdrs = TestPut_Mob_CDRs_To_FakturaPos(MasterMandantConnectionString:=MasterMandantConnectionString,
                                   StartDate:=StartDate,
                                   EndDate:=EndDate,
                                   Mob_Nr:=Mob_Nr)
                For Each currentError In MobCdrs
                    If (currentError <> "") Then
                        ListView1.Items.Add(currentError)
                    End If
                Next
                If n > ProgressBar1.Maximum Then
                    n = ProgressBar1.Maximum
                End If
                ProgressBar1.Value = n
            End If
        Next
        ListView1.Items.Insert(0, getImportInfo(), 0)
        labelInfo.Text = "Test successfully completed."
    End Sub
  Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged
        ProgressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage
    End Sub

    Private Sub Frm_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing 
If BackgroundWorker1 IsNot Nothing Then
        Me.BackgroundWorker1.CancelAsync()
        Me.Close()
    End If
```

End Sub

Using [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker?view=netframework-4.8), I tried to apply BackgroundWorker to my "TestPut_All_CDRs_To_FakturaPos" function, unfortunately failed because I get on ProgressBar1.Maximum error = ***"System.InvalidOperationException: "Invalid cross threading operation: The ProgressBar1 control was accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created for."***Please suggest, where am I making an exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is separate the user interface parts (like ListViews, MessageBoxes, etc.) from the backgroundworker.

- The way to get the data into the BGW is to pass an object into its [`.Argument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.doworkeventargs.argument?view=netframework-4.8).
- To get data out of it while it is running, use the ReportProgress event and pass whatever you want in the [`.UserState`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.progresschangedeventargs.userstate?view=netframework-4.8) object.
- To get data from it when it has finished, use the [`.Result`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.doworkeventargs.result?view=netframework-4.8) property.

We won't be using any result in this case, but I will set it up as a Boolean in case you want to modify it. So, let's create classes to get the data in and out...

```
Private Class BgwArgs
    Property StartDate As DateTime
    Property EndDate As DateTime

    Property MinNr As Integer
    Property MaxNr As Integer

    Property ConnStr As String

End Class

Private Class ProgressReportData
    Property ErrorMessages As List(Of String)

End Class
```

The initial setup for the BGW is like this:

```
Private Sub Btn_OK_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Btn_OK.Click
    ListView1.Items.Clear()
    ResetCounter()

    Dim args As New BgwArgs With {.StartDate = dtp_Start.Value,
                                  .EndDate = dtp_End.Value,
                                  .MinNr = CInt(tb_Min_Nr.Value),
                                  .MaxNr = CInt(tb_Max_Nr.Value),
                                  .ConnStr = "your connection string"}

    ProgressBar1.Minimum = 0
    ProgressBar1.Maximum = 100

    BackgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = True
    BackgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True

    BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(args)

End Sub
```

and then all the parts:

```
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    Dim worker As BackgroundWorker = TryCast(sender, BackgroundWorker)

    e.Result = TestPut_All_CDRs_To_FakturaPos(worker, e)

End Sub

Private Function TestPut_All_CDRs_To_FakturaPos(worker As BackgroundWorker, e As DoWorkEventArgs) As Boolean

    Dim importedInfo As New List(Of String)

    Dim args = CType(e.Argument, BgwArgs)
    Dim masterMandantConnectionString = args.ConnStr
    Dim startDate = args.StartDate
    Dim endDate = args.EndDate
    Dim min_Nr = args.MinNr
    Dim max_Nr = args.MaxNr

    Dim n As Integer = 0
    Dim totalMobs = max_Nr - min_Nr + 1

    For mob_Nr = min_Nr To max_Nr
        n += 1
        If worker.CancellationPending Then
            e.Cancel = True
        Else
            Dim mobCdrs = TestPut_Mob_CDRs_To_FakturaPos(MasterMandantConnectionString:=masterMandantConnectionString,
                               StartDate:=startDate,
                               EndDate:=endDate,
                               Mob_Nr:=mob_Nr)

            Dim pct = n * 100 \ totalMobs
            Dim progReport As New ProgressReportData With {.ErrorMessages = mobCdrs.Where(Function(m) Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(m)).ToList()}

            worker.ReportProgress(pct, progReport)

        End If
    Next

    Return True

End Function

Private Sub backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged
    Dim progData = CType(e.UserState, ProgressReportData)
    ProgressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage
    If progData.ErrorMessages IsNot Nothing Then
        For Each m In progData.ErrorMessages
            ListView1.Items.Add(m)
        Next
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
    If (e.Error IsNot Nothing) Then
        ProgressBar1.ForeColor = Color.Red
        MessageBox.Show(e.Error.Message, "Exception", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)

    ElseIf e.Cancelled Then
        ' Next, handle the case where the user cancelled the operation.
        ' Note that due to a race condition in the DoWork event handler, the Cancelled flag may not have been set, even though CancelAsync was called.
        ProgressBar1.ForeColor = Color.HotPink

    Else
        ProgressBar1.ForeColor = Color.LawnGreen
        ListView1.Items.Insert(0, GetImportInfo(), 0)
        labelInfo.Text = "Test successfully completed."

        ' We could use e.Result here if something useful was returned in it.
        ' Dim flag = CType(e.Result, Boolean)

    End If

End Sub
```

The progress percentage is calculated in the loop, as that's an easy way to get it done.

I couldn't test it, but hopefully there's enough there for you to get working code.

(I use Option Infer On and Option Strict On.)

Comment: @Mara I guess you created a BGW by dragging it onto the form in the designer, in which case please select it and then press F4 to show its properties, and change WorkerReportsProgress and WorkerSupportsCancellation to True. Hopefully that'll make it all work properly!